# Coredata in ios keyboard extension

Tags: ios, core-data, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, ios-app-group

I read below github page and used the code for sharing `coredata` between my ios Keyboard Extension and the app.

https://github.com/maximbilan/iOS-Shared-CoreData-Storage-for-App-Groups

The code is working right on the simulator but it is not working but `addPersistentStore` not working on real device:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)

    let directory = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:"group.testKeyboard.asanpardakht.ir")!

    let url = directory.appendingPathComponent("AsanPardakhtSharedData.sqlite")

    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: url, options: nil)
    } catch var error as NSError {
        coordinator = nil
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        abort()
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }
    print("\(String(describing: coordinator?.persistentStores))")
    return coordinator
}()
```

I get below errors:

> NSError   domain: "NSCocoaErrorDomain" - code: 512
>
> "reason" : "Failed to create file; code = 1"

I tried setting `RequestOpenAccess` to `YES` in my `info.plist` file but it is not still working. Does someone has any idead about the problem?

Comment: Do you have the entitlements setup for the app group "group.testKeyboard.asanpardakht.ir"?

Comment: yes, for both keyboard target and app target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that below post works right for keyboard extension too:

https://github.com/maximbilan/iOS-Shared-CoreData-Storage-for-App-Groups

The only problem is that for keyboard extension we should also set `RequestOpenAccess` at `info.plist` to `YES`.

When set it to `YES` in the setting of the keyboard an option appears for the `Full Access` we should turn it On and then the code also works on real device.

Developers should make sure that before calling the method in the quest ask user to turn the option to On.